# Update Access 2003 MDB to point to a different SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Access 2003 / SQL Server - how can I update Access 2003 MDB (`Connect` property) to point to a different SQL Server database? The new SQL Server database is on the same instance as the old one.

Comment: You can use the linked table manage ( http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/refresh_links.php ) or vba, which do you want?

Comment: You can also you use the properties pane in a passthrough query to select a new ODBC connection to the different SQL Server, but you need to make a new ODBC connection or update the old(if you update the old then the passthrough query shouldn't need to be changed, I thnk).

Answer (score 0):

I have several MS Access 2003/SQL Server applications that I manage.  All of them dynamically attach to the correct database at startup.  Some of them even connect to multiple databases on different servers during the start up sequence.  All of them use the same basic vba routine to actually dynamically attach a table to the correct server.  This is not my code, I found it by googling around the internet, but I have lost the reference to it now, so apologies in advance to the authors.

Before showing the code, to put it in context, I normally have a form "frmInitApp" with a data source that is a local config table, with a field named "ID". I start the access application from the AutoExec macro which opens this form with a filter of "ID=1".  I have other forms to manipulate this config table and change the IDs around, so to switch between production and test I just change which entry has ID=1.

I also have another local table, tableList, with a list of Access tables that I want to connect dynamically to a SQL Server.  Most applications have another field in this table for the SQL Server table name (so they don't have to be the same) - some applications have an additional field to specify which database.  But the more complex the more other spaghetti you need - I often end up with another table of connection strings to all the separate databases I might connect to etc etc.  To keep it simple just have the connection string in a field in the config table that is the datasource to frmInitApp.

We get started with the current event on frmInitApp.

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
        If Me.Filter = "" Then 'If nobody has told us what record to use then use id=1
            Me.Filter = "[ID]=1"
            configID = 1
        Else
            configID = CInt(Mid(Me.Filter, 6)) 'We are assuming the load criteria are "[ID]=..."
        End If

        Me.messages = "Connecting to databases ..."
        DoCmd.Hourglass True
        Me.stage = "InitialStartup" 'Set the stage which is to be executed during timer phase
        Me.TimerInterval = 100 'We set the time to go off to so we can let autoexec finish and let us control focus
    End Sub
```

and then in the timer we can link to the tables via an attach table function with I'll put further down the answer.  Note also that we relink pass through queries as well so they point to the new database also.  Also note that we start Open a new form a login one fore users as soon as we have attached to the first table.  I don't show the conclusion where will probably have to validate username and password against the attached table when its all done, but its trivial to figure out anyway.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbRs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbOK As Boolean
    Dim SQL As String

    Dim startedLogon As Boolean
    Me.TimerInterval = 0
    Select Case Me.stage
    Case "InitialStartup"
        Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
        startedLogon = False
        If CurrentProject.AllForms("frmLogon").IsLoaded Then
            'If its already loaded this NOT the first time through, but still need to logon ...
            If Form_frmLogon.configID = configID Then
                startedLogon = True 'unless its the same config
            End If
        End If
        dbOK = True
        Set dbRs = New ADODB.Recordset
        dbRs.Open "SELECT localname,servername FROM tableList", conn
        While dbOK And Not dbRs.EOF
        'PLEASE NOTE - WHILST THEORETICALLY "localname" and "servername" could be different the migration process
        'requires that they be the same.  Do not consider changing this until after migration is completed

            dbOK = AttachTable(dbRs("localname"), "dbo." & dbRs("servername"))
            dbRs.MoveNext
            If Not startedLogon And dbOK Then
                DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogon"      '#554 Just in case its alread open - we need to pick up new params
                DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogon", , , , , , Nz(Me.lastUserId, "") & ":" & configID
                Form_frmLogon.SetFocus              '#748 Give it focus
                startedLogon = True
            End If
        Wend
        dbRs.Close
        If dbOK Then

             Me.messages = "Relinking Common Queries ..."
             DoEvents

             Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef, cs As String

             cs = getStrConnDAO 'get the DAO connection string
             For Each qd In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
                 If Len(qd.Connect & vbNullString) > 0 Then
                     qd.Connect = cs
                 End If
             Next

        End If
        Me.messages = "Awaiting User Log On"
        DoCmd.Hourglass False
        DoEvents
        ... the rest just managing logon
End Sub
```

The attached table function

```
'//Name     :   AttachTable
    '//Purpose  :   Create a linked table to SQL Server without using a DSN
    '//Parameters
    '//     stLocalTableName: Name of the table that you are creating in the current database
    '//     stRemoteTableName: Name of the table that you are linking to on the SQL Server database
Private Function AttachTable(stLocalTableName As String, stRemoteTableName As String)
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim stConnect As String
    Me.messages = "Connecting to Database Table " & Me.mainDatabase & "." & stRemoteTableName
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number <> 3265 Then GoTo AttachTable_Err 'v4.0.44 - allow delete errors
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo AttachTable_Err
    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, getStrConnDAO(configID))
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    DoEvents
    AttachTable = True
    Exit Function

AttachTable_Err:

    AttachTable = False
    errMsg = "AttachTable encountered an unexpected error: " & Err.description & " on table " & stRemoteTableName & " in database " & Me.mainDatabase

End Function
```

You will need to getConStrDAO function

```
Private ADOconnStr As String
Private DAOconnStr As String
Public Function getStrConn(Optional configID As Long = 0) As String
    'create a connection string for use when running stored procedures
    'this uses the saved value if possible, but global variables are reset if an error occurs
    If ADOconnStr = "" Then
        Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim account As String
        Dim revealedPassword As String
        Dim s As String, i As Integer, x As String
        Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
        If configID = 0 Then configID = Nz(Form_frmLogon.configID, 0)
        Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT *  FROM localConfig WHERE id =" & configID)
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            ADOconnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER="  'this provider is needed to allow use of SP as form.recordset
            ADOconnStr = ADOconnStr & rs("ServerName") & ";DATABASE=" & rs("DatabaseName") & ";UID="
            ADOconnStr = ADOconnStr & rs("dbUser") & ";PWD=" & EncryptDecrypt(Nz(rs("dbPassword"), ""))
        End If
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set conn = Nothing
    End If
    getStrConn = ADOconnStr
End Function
Public Sub resetConnection()
    ADOconnStr = ""
    DAOconnStr = ""
End Sub
Function getStrConnDAO(Optional configID As Long = 0) As String
    If DAOconnStr = "" Then
        Dim a As New ADODB.Connection
        a.Open getStrConn(configID)
        DAOconnStr = "ODBC;driver=SQL Server;" & a.Properties("Extended Properties") & ";"
        Set a = Nothing
    End If
    getStrConnDAO = DAOconnStr
End Function
```

And finally a simple encryption of database password to make it not obvious to casual eyes - something again copied from the internet

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Comments:   Performs XOr encryption/decryption on string data. Passing a
'''             string through the procedure once encrypts it, passing it
'''             through a second time decrypts it.
'''
''' Arguments:  szData          [in|out] A string containing the data to
'''                             encrypt or decrypt.
'''
''' Date        Developer       Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 05/18/05    Rob Bovey       Created
'''
Public Function EncryptDecrypt(szData As String) As String

    Const lKEY_VALUE As Long = 215

    Dim bytData() As Byte
    Dim lCount As Long

    bytData = szData

    For lCount = LBound(bytData) To UBound(bytData)
        bytData(lCount) = bytData(lCount) Xor lKEY_VALUE
    Next lCount

    EncryptDecrypt = bytData

End Function
```